# Value in TextView doesn't update

Tags: java, android

There is the following code from custom AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {     
        setTitle();
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void setTitle() {
        Activity activity=(Activity)context;
        TextView title=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textViewToDoListTitle);
        Log.e("title", title.getText().toString());
        title.setText("123");
        Log.e("title", title.getText().toString());
    }
```

This code works without exceptions, but setTitle() function doesn't update text in TextView title! In log I can see that title stores "123" after executing the last row in setTitle(). But the value doesn't update on the screen! How can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you get the context from? And if you're actually trying to update a TextView in an Activity from inside the AsyncTask, then when this code actually fires, you should actually get an exception, because of the crossthreading. It will tell you something like: "Trying to change a view from another thread than the thread creating the view or something."

Comment: I can change data from UI in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). Look at the documentation.

Comment: Ah yeah - sorry ;-)
Instead of passing the context from the Activity, I would pass the reference to the TextView instead and then calling setText directly on the TextView - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, your solution is right. Please, make a different answer and I will mark it as the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the original reference to the TextView instead of the context to the Activity and then calling setText on the TextView, should work ;-)